# Entry point functions analysis

Tags: c++, multithreading, process, dependencies, shared-libraries

i want to ask about what the entry points in dependency walker are>

Are they the locations of where the functions from dll's are loaded into memory?

What is Ordinal and Hint?

At the bottom of dependcy walker, it says `DllMain(0x00007FFF78390000, DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, 0x0000000000000001) in "NCRYPT.DLL" called by thread 1. DllMain(0x00007FFF78390000, DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, 0x0000000000000001) in "NCRYPT.DLL" returned 1 (0x1) by thread 1.`

Does this mean that the process detached from NCRYPT.DLL? What are the first and second memory addresses?

Thank you for your help! :)

Update: You need at least 10 reputation to post images.
can only post the link sorry

[[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GPoB.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GPoB.png)

Comment: I have read it thank you, jsut not sure what the entry points in dependency walker refer to. It seems like memory addresses for functions of the same library while the entry point function is a main function in a single dynamic library

Answer (score 0):

`Does this mean that the process detached from NCRYPT.DLL?` - yes.

`What are the first and second memory addresses?` - only the first is an address, the module base of this dll, the second is a flag indicating that the process is terminating.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dllmain) (*lpvReserved* in comment section).